# Tsql select from related table with AND condition

Tags: sql, t-sql

I've two related tables:

Table1

```
Id
-----
1
2
3
```

Table2

```
Id     Feature
--------------
1      Car
1      Moto
1      Camper
2      Moto
2      Scooter
3      Apple
```

I want to select Ids which have, for example, both 'Car' AND 'Moto'.
So in the example i want to get only Id = 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `INTERSECT` operator:

```
select id from table2 where feature = 'Car'
intersect 
select id from table2 where feature = 'Moto'
```

Comment: I think you meant `table2` in the first `SELECT`.

Comment: Fantastic this intersect operator! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
WITH    features AS
        (
        SELECT  feature
        FROM    (
                VALUES
                ('Car'),
                ('Moto')
                ) q (feature)
        )
SELECT  *
FROM    table1 t1
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
        (
        SELECT  feature
        FROM    features
        EXCEPT
        SELECT  feature
        FROM    table2 t2
        WHERE   t2.id = t1.id
        )
```

or this:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    table t1
WHERE   (
        SELECT  COUNT(*)
        FROM    table2 t2
        WHERE   t2.id = t1.id
                AND t2.feature IN ('Car', 'Moto')
        ) = 2
```

Which query is more efficient depends on how many records you have in both tables and how many matches there are.

Answer (score 0):

This select does two `LEFT OUTER JOIN`s to `table2` (one based on 'Car' and the other based on 'Moto') and makes sure that each `JOIN` returned a result. The `DISTINCT` ensures that you get each ID only once.

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.id
FROM table2 t2
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 t2_2 ON t2.id = t2_2.id AND t2_2.feature = 'Moto'
WHERE t2.feature = 'Car'
AND t2_2.id IS NOT NULL
```

**Edit:** Removed join to table1 since it really isn't needed.

Comment: Derek's answer using `INTERSECT` is probably faster than this.